# expand within notebook does not work as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Here are attempts to get a Widget to stay in the center of the screen as the window re-sizes.  By that I mean the normal behavior of a grid `sticky='ew'` with the frame packed to expand and `fill='x'`.  Here is some demo code to show what I mean:

```
from Tkinter import Frame,Button,Label
from ttk import Notebook

root = Frame()
root.pack(expand=True,fill='both')
nb = Notebook(root)

btn_f = Frame(nb)
Button(btn_f, text="Button Packed").pack(pady=100,padx=100)
# btn_f.pack(expand=True,fill='both') #makes no difference if this is removed

lbl_f = Frame(nb)
Label(lbl_f, text="This label is in a grid").grid(pady=100,sticky='ew')
# lbl_f.grid() #makes no difference if this is removed

nb.add(btn_f, text="Button")
nb.add(lbl_f, text="Label")

nb.pack(expand=True,fill='x')

root.mainloop()
```

My suspicion has to do with what I discovered about commenting out the pack and expand.  Does the add method in Notebook run it's own layout manager to handle how the frame is placed in it?  What I'm asking is how do I achieve the affect of centering with grid, like what I demonstrated in the first tab using pack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code makes it behave the same as the packed `button`.

```
lbl_f = Frame(nb)
Label(lbl_f, text="This label is in a grid").grid(pady=100,sticky='ew')
lbl_f.grid()
lbl_f.rowconfigure('all', weight=1)
lbl_f.columnconfigure('all', weight=1)
```

As you can see, `row`/`columnfigure` are applied to the `frame` element.

---

P.S.
I would suggest you modify your code slightly. It makes it easier down the road if you change the widgets as such (for example):

```
Button(btn_f, text="Button Packed").pack(pady=100,padx=100)
```

to

```
packedButton = Button(btn_f, text="Button Packed")
packedButton.pack(pady=100,padx=100)
```

This way, you can refer to the button (or whatever widget) later on. You cannot create/pack(or grid) the widget on the same line though; it must be down separately as shown here.

Another positive change would be to use classes. There are a lot of examples on SO, but if the code in this question is just a quick sample then more power to you. Good luck!

Comment: What does row/columnconfigure do?  I'm a bit confused by their use.  I pulled this example out of a class to give an example of what the question.

Comment: You basically configure how the frame uses its rows and columns. In this case, you assign a "weight", which determines how it rows/columns grow when given more space. If you don't include it, it defaults to 0 and they don't grow at all. 1 makes them grow, 2 twice as much, etc.